# Are new flags for comments working?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7029/the-great-wordpress-admin-menu-challenge-of-jan-2011-a-k-a-how-to-resolve-some/7034#7034) with [new "not an answer" option](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), but I don't see the [flag in moderation tools](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tools/flagged) and I don't see my flag count going down when I tried it again.

Bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I currently see two things you have flagged as not an answer, so...

Comment: Than you for checking. So flagging itself does work, why it doesn't show up in moderation tools? I remember I saw my own flags in the past when flagging for spam.

Comment: @rarst mod flags are not the same as spam and offensive flags; mod flags are considered private; they are only visible to moderators not to 10k users.